# Como criar um atalho para abrir um site no navegador?

Tags: android

Preciso criar um atalho para abrir o navegador com o endereço (no caso, o Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

Pra fazer o que você quer, você precisa criar um atalho do Windows. Se o atalho apontar para um endereço Web, o navegador padrão do sistema será aberto, com uma nova aba já focada e a carregar o endereço indicado no atalho.

Para criar um atalho do Windows programaticamente, você pode usar a ferramenta [MKLINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx) do sistema. Você pode fazer um programa na sua linguagem preferida que invoque esse programa, com os parâmetros necessários (detalhados no link acima).

Caso você queira fazer isso em outro sistema operacional, edite a pergunta pra incluir essa informação, ok?

Comment: é um VBS que preciso, mas precisava fazer isso no Android

Comment: Nesse caso eu recomendo que você dê uma olhada nesse link, de uma pergunta no SO matriz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676090/android-is-there-a-programming-way-to-create-a-web-shortcut-on-home-screen . O que você quer é possível, tem só que seguir os passos indicados nas respostas de lá.